# How to show response from react redux on multiple pages?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm new in react and im asking you for help.
I'm trying to show response from JSON using react redux on multiple pages. For example response-"name" i want to display in user.js, and response-"email" plan to display in details.js. problem is i dont know where/how to start.

```
const showUserApi = () => {
  return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      return json.users;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
};
```

this is my code to fetch data, but don't know how can i customize it to show data on others pages.
Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2):

What you are facing right now is exactly the problem with react, to overcome this issue, redux was introduced to handle this side effect.

You need to explore the concepts and implementation of redux store, actions, reducers and a middleware (optional) to handle data storage and passing through every component inside the project.

I am adding couple of links below to help you in exploring.

https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/redux-in-24-lines-of-code/

https://www.bing.com/images/search?view=detailV2&ccid=LKg44hjg&id=D3361DA1EFF409F9196DFDC9E75EE3F5932D1467&thid=OIP.LKg44hjgvTU_A7bZL2xtigHaEJ&mediaurl=https%3a%2f%2fimages.yourstory.com%2fcs%2f1%2f7db395f0-0daf-11e9-9820-1f4fb7912c4d%2fRedux-Data-flow1556794082934.png%3ffm%3dpng%26auto%3dformat%26blur%3d500&exph=280&expw=500&q=redux+architecture&simid=608009563979395182&FORM=IRPRST&ck=A0574DE6078EA7FF87B33A5E7E2195B7&selectedIndex=58&ajaxhist=0&ajaxserp=0